# How to search for POSTS containing brackets?

Tags: support, search, search-engine

I want to search if anyone has asked anything about [how-to-ask]. I typed `\[how-to-ask]` (brings me `\[how-to-ask]`), `\[how-to-ask\]` (brings me `\[how-to-ask]`) and `[how-to-ask\]` (brings a non-existent tag). Does anyone know how to search for such stuffs?

Comment: searching for [{()}]":;.,<>!@#$%^&*() is seriously broken in SE search. You might have some luck with SEDE or use Google instead.